# Recursive promise not working

Tags: javascript, recursion, promise

I'm playing around with promises to try and recursively walk a nested array structure.  Here is my test code:

```
const Promise = require("Bluebird");

let allPaths = [
    "foo",
    "bar",
    [
        "baz",
        "bazzz",
        "bazzzzz",
        "xxx",
        [
            "never"
        ]
    ],
    "abc",
    [
        "tst",
        [
            "111",
            "222"
        ],
        "xxx"
    ],
    "zzz"
];

function processThisPath(path) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        if (typeof path === "string") {
            console.log(`Processing path ${path}`);
            return resolve(path);
        }
        else {
            return new Promise(function(resolve) {
                console.log("PROCESSING NEW LEVEL");
                return Promise.each(
                    path,
                    processThisPath
                );
            });
        }
    });
}

Promise.each(
    allPaths,
    function(currentPath) {
        return (
            processThisPath(currentPath)
            .catch(function(err) {
                console.log(`Cannot traverse '${currentPath}': ${err.message}`);
            })
        );
    }
);
```

It doesn't traverse the entire structure and I can't figure out why.  The output is:

```
Processing path foo
Processing path bar
PROCESSING NEW LEVEL
Processing path baz
Processing path bazzz
Processing path bazzzzz
Processing path xxx
PROCESSING NEW LEVEL
Processing path never
```

Why does it not move on to `"abc"`?  I'd have thought the initial `Promise.each` would move on to the next entry in the array, but it seems to have stopped when it got to the first array.  Why?

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Comment: It stops when you never call `resolve` in the `new Promise(function(resolve) {
                console.log("PROCESSING NEW LEVEL"); … })`

Comment: Adding `resolve();` doesn't change the output.

Comment: Also does the Promise constructor antipattern apply here?  I don't have already-existing promises.  If it does please reply with an answer and show how to fix it.

Comment: you certainly have multiple already-existing promises inside that `new Promise` call. The obvious one is the inner `new Promise`, the other is the return value of `Promise.each`. You should simply write `function processThisPath(path) { if (…) return Promise.resolve(…); else return Promise.each(paths, processThisPath); }`

Comment: Ah, you also didn't call the `resolve()` of the outer promise in the `else` path, that's why it still stopped after the `each` now

Comment: @Bergi Please give an example of how to fix this in an answer, I'm not really understanding your comments.

Comment: I think it's incorrect to imply that I am going to use the "already-existing" promises inside `processThisPath` (unless I am misunderstanding) - `return Promise.resolve()` still creates a new Promise and returns it, no?

Comment: But that's not inside a `new Promise` callback. Surely you have to create new promises inside `processThisPath`, but you should never put such inside a `new Promise`. Btw, where in your code does the actual asynchronous processing happen? Your example code doesn't actually need any promises.

Comment: Bergi: I'm just structuring it for now.  I want the "console.log" statements to be done asynchronously to simulate actual I/O work.  And that's where I'm confused.  This code: `if (typeof path === "string") { console.log(`Processing path ${path}`); return Promise.resolve(); }` will *immediately* execute the `console.log` and return the Promise, rather than executing the `console.log` as a promise callback.

Comment: To simulate actual IO, better use `new Promise(resolve => { console.log("Working"); setTimeout(resolve, 500); })`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156481/discussion-between-jez-and-bergi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the `new Promise` antipattern and I had forgotten that `processThisPath` was already running as a callback, called by `Promise.each(...)`.  Therefore it's OK to just do my simulation of the I/O operation directly:

```
function processThisPath(path) {
    if (typeof path === "string") {
        console.log(`Processing path ${path}`);
        return Promise.resolve();
    }
    else {
        console.log("PROCESSING NEW LEVEL");
        return Promise.each(path, processThisPath);
    }
}
```

Here, the `Promise.resolve()` which is returned is simulating the call to an async library that would be doing something like disk I/O, outside this thread.  When using that library, the result of the async library function would be returned instead of `Promise.resolve()`.  Note that although `Promise.resolve()` creates a Promise internally which is then returned, it avoids the antipattern by not explicitly using the `new Promise` constructor.